# How to solve Time exceeded problem in Best Time to buy stock simple leetcode question

Tags: python

I am solving the leetcode question of Best Time to buy stock:
I have submitted this code with one for loop and I have got time limit exceeded. I cannot figure out why.

```
class Solution(object):
def maxProfit(self, prices):
    maxPro = 0
    size = len(prices)
    for i in range(size-1,0,-1):
        minimum = min(prices[0:i])
        maxPro = max(prices[i]-minimum,maxPro)
    return maxPro
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) min() and max() functions have O(n) complexity on List, so it is basically another loop. So your  time complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response
if I replace the min() with a for loop doesn't make it the same complexity?